# Wikipedia Graph Database Insertion

Tags: sql, mysql, rdf, wikipedia

I am trying to create a database from dbpedia RDF triples. I have a table `Categories` which contains all the Categories in wikipedia. To store categorizations i have created a table with `child` and `parent` fields, both foreign keys to `Categories` table. To load categories from NTriples iam using the following SQL Query

```
INSERT INTO CatToCat (`child`, `parent`)
values((SELECT id FROM Categories WHERE BINARY identifier='Bar'),
       (SELECT id FROM Categories WHERE BINARY identifier='Bar'));
```

But the insertion is very slow.. inserting 2.5Million relationships would take very long time.. is there better way to optimize the query, schema??

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense to me.  You say that you are using SQL to query NTriples which doesn't make much sense.  I assume you already have the data imported in an SQL database.  Which partly begs the question why?  You'd probably be much better off putting the table into an RDF/Triple Store and using reasoning to infer the relationships.

Comment: I am trying to load data from NTriples into the SQL Database. My application doesnt require all of the RDF data, the predicates for instance. I could just extract this directly from wikipedia but i thought it'd be faster to load from dbpedia nt dumps. I just need the category hierarchy. I thought a triplestore might be an overkill since i dont need to use SPARQL and such.

Comment: What type of indexes have you created in the table CatToCat ?

Comment: just an autoincrementing id in CatToCat.. in Categories i have indexed the indentifier which is the unique identifier string for the category

Comment: Ok that makes much more sense of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Was some indexing issues. Made identifier in Categories unique and binary. I guess that sped up the two selects.

Answer (score 2):

you could try a Graph Database like Neo4j, with RDF layers on top, there is for instance the Tinkerpop SAIL implementation, see https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Sail-Implementation

That should work a bit better than RDBMS, at least for Neo4j.

/peter

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider loading `SELECT id, indentifier from Categories` into a hash table (or trie) on the client side, and using that to fill CatToCat. On a database the size of wikipedia, I'd expect to see a huge performance difference between constant time hash lookups and trie lookups (which are constant with respect to the number of different data items), and `log n` B-Tree lookups. (Of course, you need to have the memory available.)
2. Consider using a single PreparedStatement, with parameter binding so that MySQL doesn't have to re-parse and re-optimize the query for every insertion.

You'll have to benchmark these to figure out how much of an improvement they actually are.